# Laravel Relationship With Variables / Where

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

So I have a `StudentBursaryEnrolment` model and it has the following:

```
public function courses() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\StudentBursaryEnrolmentCourse');
}
```

Works fine in a normal scenario where I want to pull all the courses through in a view:

```
@if ($enrolment->courses)
    @foreach ($enrolment->courses as $course)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$enrolment->academic_institution->academic_institution .' - '. $course->course}}</td>
            <td class="f114">{{__($course->current_year)}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

However, I need to pull through courses that are only within certain dates, so was thinking I could just make a relationship with this in mind in the model file (to keep logic out of the view):

Something like:

```
public function active_courses($from_date,$to_date) {
    return $this->hasMany('App\StudentBursaryEnrolmentCourse')->where(function($query) use ($to_date) {
        $query->whereYear('completion_date', '>=', date('Y', strtotime($to_date)))
            ->whereYear('commencement_date','<=', date('Y', strtotime($to_date)));
    });
}
```

*(Ignoring the fact that it currently is only using '$to_date' at this stage, query isnt complete - just trying to get it working first - which its not)*

How to get this done?

Comment: what is the result when you do `$enrolment->active_courses`? did you try `->get()` at the end?

Comment: Maybe you'll need the `whereBetween()` clause on the builder. Just instantiate two carbon instances with your start and end date and go like `->whereBetween('commencement_date', [$start, $end])`. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
StudentBursaryEnrolment::with(['courses' => function ($q) {
    $q->whereDate('completion_date', '>=', '2016-12-31')->whereDate('commencement_date', '<=', '2020-12-31');
}])->get();
```

Also, if you are planning to keep your calculations in your model::class then I suggest using [Laravel Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: Thanks - To clarify, I should plug this in as a 'return' in my public function active_courses() ?

Comment: This would go in your controller. If you are planning to add a new function in your model, then yes, you will have to prepend `$q->whereDate...` with return.

Comment: Sorry @Digvijay but can you give a full answer as to how to do it under the model as this is what I am having trouble with? As my example above, I tried and couldnt get it right...